# Backup and restore ubuntu over ssh

Tags: ssh, backup, restore

I need to backup my ubuntu filesystem through ssh, save in pendrive, format and install. Can anyone point me how can I do that.

I think the steps are:

1. Connect to the server through ssh
2. Copy or create the image
3. Save the image in a pendrive
4. Format the disk
5. Rwstore from the image saved in the pendrive

How can I do that

Comment: You want to do all five steps remotely? 

Comment: Don't think you can effectively totally backup a running system. Basically you're asking to clonezilla over ssh or equivalent. I'd love to know if it can be done.

Comment: If your device happens to be an enterprise-grade server, like a Dell PowerEdge, look up Dell iDRAC and HP iLO. They are hardware devices (like KVM, but better) that let you do things like remotely control the device (even things like the BIOS, as they are hardware KVM devices) via a virtual display, mouse, and keyboard. Dell iDRAC, for example, can remotely tell the server to boot to an ISO that is stored on your client computer, let you use the mouse/keyboard/display totally remotely to interact with the server, so you could use Clonezilla, edit the BIOS, view the boot logo, etc.

Comment: My ubuntu was a ubuntu 20.04 desktop version. I would like to at least copy the services that I configured previously but that I don't remember what tuto I followed. That system was working very well and in a energy shutdown I lost the access to my OS and files. I can only access to them is through ssh